# Get referral item (link)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

We have a sitecore website and we need to know the item from which the link that brought you to page X.
Example:
You're on page A and click a link provided by item X that will lead you to page B.
On page B we need to be able to get that item X referred you, and thus access the item and it's properties.

It could go through session, Sitecore context, I don't know what and we don't even need the entire item itself, just the ID would do.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments you have a web-architecture problem that isn't really Sitecore specific.

You have a back end which consumes several data items to produce some HTML which is sent to the client. Each of those data items may produce links in the HTML. They may produce identical links. Only one of the items is considered the source of the HTML page.

You wan't to know which of those items produced the link. Your only option is to find a way of identifying the links produced. To do this you will *have to* add some form of tagging information to the URL produced(such as a querystring) that can be interpretted when the request for the URL is processed. The items themselves don't exist in the client.

The problem would be exactly the same if your links were produced by a database query. If you wanted to know which record produced the link you'd have to add an identifier to the link.

You could probably devise a system that would allow you to identify item **most** of the time (i.e. when the link clicked on was unique to that page), but it would involve either caching lots of data in a session (list of links produced and the items that produced them) or recreating the request for the referring URL. Either sounds like a lot of hassle for a non-perfect solution that could feasibly slow your server down a fair amount.

Comment: Thanks, we'll look into it and try to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

James is correct... your original parameters are basically impossible to satisfy.

With some hacking and replacing of the standard Sitecore providers though, you could track these.  But it would be far easier to use a querystring ID of some sort.

On our system, we have 3rd party advertising links... they have client javascript which actually submits the request to a local page and then gets redirected to the target URL.  So when you hover over the link, the status bar shows you "http://whatever.com"... it *appears* the link is going to whatever.com, but you are actually going to http://ourserver/redirect.aspx first so we can track that link, and then getting a Response.Redirect().

You could do something similar by providing your own LinkManager and including the generating item ID in the tracking URL, then redirecting to the actual page/item the user wants.

However... this seems rather convoluted and error-prone, and I would not recommend it.